# PSpice: value of resistor controlled by a function

Tags: simulation, spice, pspice

I am using PSpice to simulate the parasitic BJT of a power VD-MOSFET, which under certain conditions can be turned on and lead to the destruction of the cell.

I have designed a model that is working well enough, but it doesn't take into account the temperature rise because of the increased currents flowing through the cell. To achieve that, I have to add a resistor in parallel to the BJT (Rtc in the attached picture), whose value is changing throughout the simulation.

[image: Source: D. G. Walker, 2000]

As I first step, I would like Rtc to be decreased exponentially with time. 
Is there a way to establish and use a function like this in PSpice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember publishing a model of a variable resistor in Power Electronics and Intelligent Motion, the US magazine, in 2005. The idea was to control an inductance, a capacitance and a resistance by a voltage. The variable resistance model using PSpice analog behavioral equations is here:

.subckt VARIRES 1 2 CTRL

R1 1 2 1E10

G1 1 2 Value = { V(1,2)/(V(CTRL)+1u) }

.ENDS

It follows this simple model

[image]

and here is a simple test circuit using IsSpice at that time:

[image]

The 1-u source is there to prevent a divide-by-zero event and improves convergence during the bias point calculation.

Answer (score 0):

What would work for this is to use a *parametric sweep* for Rtc. More here: https://m.eet.com/media/1180248/chapter%205.pdf